# What is the difference between @types.coroutine and @asyncio.coroutine decorators?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-3.5

Documentations say:

> @asyncio.coroutine
>
> Decorator to mark generator-based coroutines. This enables the generator use yield from to call async def coroutines, and also
>   enables the generator to be called by async def coroutines, for
>   instance using an await expression.

_

> @types.coroutine(gen_func)
>
> This function transforms a generator
>   function into a coroutine function which returns a generator-based
>   coroutine. The generator-based coroutine is still a generator
>   iterator, but is also considered to be a coroutine object and is
>   awaitable. However, it may not necessarily implement the `__await__()`
>   method.

So is seems like purposes is the same - to flag a generator as a coroutine (what `async def`in Python3.5 and higher does with some features).

When need to use `asyncio.coroutine` when need to use `types.coroutine`, what is the diffrence?

Comment: Looking over the code the differences are minimal, mostly in how they accept methods. `asyncio` is a codebase that has to be compatible with earlier Python versions, while `types` is only distributed with Python itself. So you could see the `asyncio.coroutine()` as a backport of `types.coroutine()` that can be used in other Python versions.

Comment: At the latest development, asyncio.coroutine function actually call types.coroutine(coro) to wrap the result

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference is if you have a yield statement or not.
Here's the code:

```
from types import coroutine as t_coroutine
from asyncio import coroutine as a_coroutine, ensure_future, sleep, get_event_loop


@a_coroutine
def a_sleep():
    print("doing something in async")
    yield 1


@t_coroutine
def t_sleep():
    print("doing something in types")
    yield 1


async def start():
    sleep_a = a_sleep()
    sleep_t = t_sleep()
    print("Going down!")


loop = get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(start())
```

In this example everything seem same - here's the debugging info from pycharm (we're standing on the "Going down!" line). Nothing is printed in console yet, so the functions didn't start yet.

[image: PyCharm Debug]

But **if we remove the `yield`**, the `types` version will start function instantly!

```
from types import coroutine as t_coroutine
from asyncio import coroutine as a_coroutine, ensure_future, sleep, get_event_loop


@a_coroutine
def a_sleep():
    print("doing something in async")


@t_coroutine
def t_sleep():
    print("doing something in types")


async def start():
    sleep_a = a_sleep()
    sleep_t = t_sleep()
    print("Going down!")


loop = get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(start())
```

Now we have `doing something in types` in console printed. And here's the debug info:

[image: new debug info]

As you can see **it starts right after call**, if there is no result and returns None.

---

As for usage, you should use `asyncio` version always. If you need to run it like *fire and forget* (running instantly and getting results later) - use `ensure_future` function.

Answer (score 1):

One other subtle difference: generator-based coroutines decorated with `@asyncio.coroutine` will test `True` for `asyncio.iscoroutinefunction()`, while those decorated with `@types.coroutine` will test `False`.

```
# testcoro.py
import asyncio
import inspect
import types

@asyncio.coroutine
def old_coro_with_asyncio():
    yield from asyncio.sleep(1)

@types.coroutine
def old_coro_with_types():
    yield from asyncio.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for coro in (old_coro_with_asyncio, old_coro_with_types):
        print(coro.__name__, 'iscoroutine:', asyncio.iscoroutine(coro))
        print(coro.__name__, 'iscoroutinefunc:', asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(coro))
```

Output:

```
(py37) $ python3 testcoro.py 
old_coro_with_asyncio iscoroutine: False
old_coro_with_asyncio iscoroutinefunc: True
old_coro_with_types iscoroutine: False
old_coro_with_types iscoroutinefunc: False
```

Nonetheless, both of these are awaitable.

---

<sub>*Note also that this difference does not apply to their _results: replace `iscoroutinefunction()` with `iscoroutine()` (which tests for a coroutine object), and `old_coro_with_asyncio()` + `old_coro_with_types()` will evaluate False for both.</sub>

Comment: But `inspect.iscoroutinefunction(old_coro_with_asyncio)` return `False`.