# Python: recursion with async/await

Tags: python, recursion, async-await

This is some simple working code for traversing a file tree. It uses the idea of a synchronous generator:

```
def list_dir_groom(abs_path):
    """Returns the list of directories
    and the list of files ([abs_path] offspring).
    """
    dirs, files = [], []

    for i in os.listdir(abs_path):
        if i[0] != ".":
            x = abs_path.joinpath(i)
            if x.is_dir():
                dirs.append(x)
            else:
                if is_target_file(x):
                    files.append(x)

    return dirs, files


def traverse_target_tree(tgt_dir):
    """Recursively traverses the target directory [tgt_dir]
    and yields a sequence of file names.
    """
    dirs, files = list_dir_groom(tgt_dir)

    for d in dirs:
        yield from traverse_target_tree(d)

    for f in files:
        yield f


def tweak():
    """Tweak all files.
    """
    for i in traverse_target_tree(ARGS.tgt_dir):
        print(f"{i}")
```

I've been trying to rewrite it using `asyncio` (Python 3.8.1) for educational purposes. This is *not* working properly, of course:

```
async def traverse_target_tree_async(tgt_dir):
    """Recursively traverses the target directory [tgt_dir]
    and yields a sequence of file names.
    """
    dirs, files = list_dir_groom(tgt_dir)

    for d in dirs:
        yield traverse_target_tree_async(d)

    for f in files:
        yield f


async def tweak_async():
    """Tweak all files.
    """
    async for i in traverse_target_tree_async(ARGS.tgt_dir):
        print(f"{i}")

...

asyncio.run(tweak_async())
```

A sample output looks like this:

```
<async_generator object traverse_target_tree_async at 0x7f4993429ca0>
<async_generator object traverse_target_tree_async at 0x7f4993429d30>
<async_generator object traverse_target_tree_async at 0x7f4993429ca0>
<async_generator object traverse_target_tree_async at 0x7f4993429d30>
/home/user/spaces/python/tex-tweak/n.vim
/home/user/spaces/python/tex-tweak/README.md
/home/user/spaces/python/tex-tweak/pyproject.toml
/home/user/spaces/python/tex-tweak/poetry.lock
```

It, in a way, stands to reason, yet I have no idea what final step I am supposed to do.

Comment: It would be difficult to test your script as it is not a minimal executable example. But anyway, it may work if you change `yield traverse_target_tree_async(d)` to `yield from traverse_target_tree_async(d)`.

Comment: `yield from` in the async context is a syntax error, and rightfully so.

Comment: Ah, I don't even know that... How about manually expand that using `async for`? This answer should be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47378063/5588279

Comment: Side-note: `os.listdir` is strictly worse than `os.scandir`, especially when you want to do stuff like test if it's a directory (which the `DirEntry` returned by `scandir` can tell you for free, while your current approach requires a `stat` per file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47376408/why-cant-i-yield-from-inside-an-async-function). Thanks to [Sraw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5588279/sraw).

```
async def traverse_target_tree_async(tgt_dir):
    """Recursively traverses the target directory [tgt_dir]
    and yields a sequence of file names.
    """
    dirs, files = list_dir_groom(tgt_dir)

    for d in dirs:
        async for f in traverse_target_tree_async(d):
            yield f

    for f in files:
        yield f
```