# Generator-based coroutines being deprecated in python 3.7

Tags: python, generator, python-3.7, coroutine

Generator-based coroutines [were being deprecated in python 3.7 and scheduled for removal in python 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-task.html#generator-based-coroutines).

The use of `@asyncio.coroutine` [was also deprecated in python 3.7 and scheduled for removal in python 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.coroutine). It already issues a deprecation warning if used.

On the other hand, `@types.coroutine` [is not said to be deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/types.html#types.coroutine) and doesn't issue a warning.

[Another SO discussion on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57116858/2085626) already noted that `@asyncio.coroutine` uses `@types.coroutine` and adds the deprecation warning, among other stuff.

The use of `@types.coroutine` is required for *awaiting* on *generator-based coroutines*, otherwise you get the error:

```
"object generator can't be used in 'await' expression"
```

(The use of generators to create coroutines is still relevant when you have a value at hand that you just wish to ***yield*** as is - **not *yield from***).

**Would the *@types.coroutine* decorator remain valid in future python versions?**

In case it remains valid, would generators decorated with `@types.coroutine` be considered as valid *coroutines*, i.e. not fall under the deprecation of *generator-based coroutines*?

Comment: I think the only way to answer this is to ask [the Python bug tracker](https://bugs.python.org/). Seems like the intent was to deprecate everything but `async def`, but who knows?

Comment: Maybe a better way to ask this is "What is the preferred way of using coroutines in Python 3.7?" In the current form it's probably impossible to answer, which is why I started a close vote.